Store Named Attribute with Geometry Proximity to control Shader Nodes
I want to  control the strength of an emission material via the geometry proximity node. I am seeing correct output values on the distance value in my sheet, but seeing no change in the str of the light, even when ramping up to extreme values. Please help.




I’m pretty sure you have to store it on faces, not points, for the material to see it.

For your problem, it does not matter if the attribute is stored in Point domain or in Face domain. In Face domain, the color is uniform per face ; in Point domain, it is interpolated per pixel.

I am suspecting (with only a partial view of the GeometryNodes graph...) that the issue is with the material of the instances, that is not the material of the object to which the GN modifier is attached. Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

I've solved my issue.
It seems that using attribute nodes does not work within the nodes used for lights (I was using an area light.)
Instead, I wound up having to create an emission shader which hides the geometry from the scene, but keeps the light emission and allows full transmission (so there isn't a big black obj)

Next, the method I was using was incredibly slow to calculate. There is no need to store the named attribute since I can just read the position of the input object in order to get the distance.
Lastly, I only needed proximity to the positions of the mesh line that the instances are being spawned on. So I made a duplicate object with a geometry node setup that was identical, but only output the mesh line vertices. This drastically reduced calculation time from .97ms to .14ms. This allows me to go from choppy playback speed to almost full smooth 24fps (22-23fps avg)


